# Why is the integral of $\frac1{x^2}$ from $1$ to $\infty$ not the same as the infinite sum from $1$ to $\infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Studying series I am a bit confused on this point. The infinite sum of $1/x^2$ from $1$ to $\infty$ was proved by Euler to be $\pi^2$ divided by $6$:

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac 1 {x^2}=\frac {\pi^2} 6$$

But if I integrate from $1$ to $\infty$ of the same entity namely $1/x^2$ it is $1$. Correct..? Unless I did it wrong. 
$$\int_1^\infty\frac 1 {x^2}dx=1$$
How can this be since by integrating it seems we are adding a lot more numbers to cover the same area so we should by all means get the same thing or something **at least as large as $\pi^2/6$**?

Comment: Why would anyone expect them to be the same?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, please read his entire question.

Comment: The relationship between the sum and the integral is given by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler–Maclaurin_formula. they differ because rectangles are not curved. The area in the rectangles is not the area under the curve.

Comment: @Sedumjoy, please read your edited question for how to write the integral and sum :).

Comment: I agree with @LordSharktheUnknown, it is not natural to expect that $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2},\qquad g(x)=\frac{1}{\lfloor x\rfloor ^2}$$ have the same integral over $(1,+\infty)$, also because $g(x)\geq f(x)$.

Comment: thank you Jose Carlos Santos for editing my mess, it looks so much better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do the sum, you sort of approximate the area with rectangles of base length equal to $1$. Draw the function $1/x^2$ and draw the rectangles with base length 1; you'll see that the area under the rectangles is much bigger than the area under the function $1/x^2$

Here is an illustration for the function $1/x$, but it's essentially the same as in the $1/x^2$ case. (Thanks to @FoobazJohn)[image: lIntegral Test]
The integral adds a lot more numbers, but these numbers are multiplied by something very small. The end result is that the integral represents the area under the $1/x^2$ curve, which is less than the area under the rectangles.

Answer (score 7):

Note that
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\leq\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}\tag{1}
$$
by considering a Riemann sum with left endpoints. Here is a picture (for the case of $1/x$ but a similar picture can be drawn for this case as well). See this picture. Image credits go to Wikipedia. [image: lIntegral Test]

Comment: +1 For the picture.. It illustrates the point better :) I will add it to my answer

Comment: no its the wrong graph, should be a graph of $\frac{1}{x^2}$, right?

Comment: @FoobazJohn, Just wondering, what program did you use to make this picture?

Comment: @mathreadler, yeah you're right, though the basic insight remains the same.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes I commented that it is for $1/x$ but a similar picture can be drawn for the case $1/x^2$.

Comment: Yes, but there is a big difference, the harmonic series does not converge. Also the corresponding integral is $\log(x)$ and as we know $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to \infty}\log(x) = \infty$

Comment: An aesthetic and notational suggestion: perhaps change $$\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\le\sum_1^\infty\frac1{n^2}\tag1$$ to $$\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}\le\sum_{x=1}^\infty\frac1{x^2}$$ where the left sum of course takes $\Delta x=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Let us compare $1$ and $\int_1^2\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$. Since $\bigl(\forall x\in(1,2]\bigr):\frac1{x^2}<1$, $\int_1^2\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx<1$. For the same reason, $\int_2^3\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx<\frac14$, $\int_3^4\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx<\frac19$, and so on. So$$1=\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^2}\,\mathrm dx<\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6.$$

Note that it is *not* true that $\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is the sum of all numbers $f(x)$ with $x\in[a,b]$. Instead, it is the *average value* of $f$ in $[a,b]$ times $b-a$.

Comment: all three answers are very good in explaining this  and I will pick one to close the problem but they are equally good....I feel stupid for not seeing this that I had to ask....